# Issue with the Entity Manager and phpunit in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony-2.1

I have an issue with my Entity Manager in phpunit.

This is my test :

```
public function testValidChangeEmail()
{
    $client = self::createAuthClient('user','password');

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/edit/30');
    $crawler = $client->submit($crawler->selectButton('submit')->form(array(
        'form[email]' => 'new@email.com',
    )));

    /*
     * With this em, this work perfectly 
     * $em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
     */

    $user = self::$em->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->findUser('new@email.com');

    die(var_dump($user->getEmail()));
}
```

and this is my WebTestCase which extends original WebTestCase :

```
class WebTestCase extends BaseWebTestCase
{
    static protected $container;
    static protected $em;

    static protected function createClient(array $options = array(), array $server = array())
    {
        $client = parent::createClient($options, $server);
        self::$em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        self::$container = $client->getContainer();

        return $client;
    }

    protected function createAuthClient($user, $pass)
    {
        return self::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => $user,
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => $pass,
        ));
    }
```

As you can see, I replace the self::$em when I created my client.

My issue :

In my test, the `die()` give me the old email and not the new email (`new@email.com`) which has registered in the test. However in my database, I have the `new@email.com` correctly saved.

When I retrieve my user in the database, I use `sefl::$em`. If I use the `$em` in comments, I retrieve the right new email.

I don't understand why in my WebTestCase, I can access to the new Entity Manager...

Comment: Side note: Why on earth do you die(var_dump()), neither do var_dump return anything useful, nor should you need to die() in the middle of a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access to the new entity manager because Symfony's client class shutdown's kernel before each request, which means that it erase whole service container and build it again from scratch.

So, after SECOND request you get very different entity manager than one you have in your own WebTestCase class. (I said after second because client shutdown's kernel only if any request has been already performed)

The question is - do you really need the same entity manafer in your WebTestCase class? Actually, you may want use the same entity manager because you want let say get controll over transaction between requests. But in this case you should create your own test client class extended symfony's one and there define static connection or entity manager, and put it into container before every request.

Look at example:
http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Symfony2-Isolation-Of-Tests

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer. In this case, I just want to test if the form saved the new email in the database. So, want is the best in your opinion ? Create my own test client to put the entity manger and container before every request ? Thank you for your help, I will can continue to work correctly !

Comment: If you want just check if something was correctly added why you don't just use entity manager from the default client (in the way you did it in your commented snippet)? I can't see any need for keeping instance of entity manager. I use my own test client in situation where I want for example check if new row was added to db AND then rollback transaction (because i don't want my test modify database).

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you for your help. I will try to implement this quickly.