# Symfony / phpUnit : functional test of a form modifying an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

How would you do a functional test (not unit tests) of a form binded to an entity ?

## Context

Let's say you have an entity "Car", with a field "id" and another field "numberPlate", and a page to edit data about a car.

*CarController.php* :

```
//...

public function imsiDetailsChangeAction(Request $request)
{
  $car_id = $request->get('car_id');
  $car = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ClnGsmBundle:Car')->Find($car_id);

  if ($simCard != null)
  {
    $form = $this->createForm(new CarType()), $car);

    if($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
      $form->bind($request);

      if ($form->isValid())
      {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('car_view', array('car_id' => $car->getId())));
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }

  return $this->render('SiteBundle:Car:carEdit.html.twig', array('car' => $car, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}

//...
```

## What I want

A test using phpUnit doing the following :

- create a Car entity with the numberPlate "QWE-456"
- load the page with the form
- using the crawler, replace the numberPlate with "AZE-123" in the form, and submit the form
- assert that my car entity's numberPlate now equals "AZE-123"

## What I tried

(just in case: my own code is a bit different, here is what I would do with the car example)

*CarControllerTest.php* :

```
//...

public function SetUp()
{
  //start kernel, stores entity manager in $this->em and client in $this->client
}

//...

public function testEditForm()
{
  $car = new Car();
  $car->setNumberPlate("QWE-456");

  $this->entityManager->persist($simCard);
  $this->em->flush();

  $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/fr/Car/edit/'.$car->getId());
  $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

  $formNode = $crawler->filterXpath("//div[@id='main']//form");
  $form = $formNode->form(array(
    'car[plateNumber]'=>'AZE-123',
  ));

  //var_dump($car->getPlateNumber());
  $this->client->submit($form);
  //var_dump($car->getPlateNumber());
  $this->assertEquals('AZE-123',$car->getPlateNumber);
}
```

I expect this test to pass, and the second var_dump to print "AZE-123" instead of "QWE-456". But my entity isn't modified.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You should refresh the data reloading it from the database: the [refresh method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#609-629) do it for you, so try this:

```
  $this->client->submit($form);

  $this->em->refresh($car);

  $this->assertEquals('AZE-123',$car->getPlateNumber);
```

I suggest you to check before the HTTP Response in order to verify the correct interaction, as example:

```
    $response = $this->client->getResponse();
    $this->assertTrue($response->isRedirection());
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for not testing it sooner ! I didn't know this method, but I should have though that the tuple in database was modified without my entity being updated... However, this solution still does not work, because "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: Car". I think that's because the kernel was started again and the database scratched (I had similar errors when trying to do several requests in one test). Are you not supposed to do it like this ? Should I override the default client to change this behavior like I saw in several answers here ?

Comment: (I'm referring to this : http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Symfony2-Isolation-Of-Tests found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823021/issue-with-the-entity-manager-and-phpunit-in-symfony-2?rq=1 (and just now I see that my question was a duplicate of this one...))

Comment: have you created the test database successfully? if you log into the test database do you see the related table?

Comment: The database used for the tests is an SQLlite database I think ? I tested overriding the client to allow other requests without rebooting the kernel (skip line 99 here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php , doing directly https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php 's doRequest when needed) and it works that way ! Also, the refresh method is not even required.